# Mac Terminal changed from @username-MacBook-Pro to @username-MBP, why?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, zsh

I was using my macOS terminal and I realised that after doing a factory reset my terminal name went from username@Username-MacBook-Pro to username@Username-MBP. Nothing else really changed but I want to know why it changed. I'm using zsh. I just like how MacBook-Pro looks to be honest.
(macOS Monterey)